# Jade: text box change the value = " ..."

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, pug

I am extremely beginner in Jade and Html and I am trying to build a form in Jade. The problem I am having is with a basic text box as follows:

```
input(type='text', name='sessionID', value = 'valueID')
```

When I need to modify `sessionID` in my code, I just do `sessionID = //some  command.`
But that does not work for `valueID = //some command.`

Is it possible to change in any way the `valueID`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like jade is just picky about value.

```
input(type='text', name='sessionID', value=valueID)
```

forces it to use valueID as a variable

I made a working case here: http://runnable.com/UWekeMufwudHAACH

Comment: This is was great! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

jade is just a templating language that produces static html, it doesn't bind data the objects.  If you want to change the value of an html  tag, you need to use javascript and select the element and then update it's value.

```
document.querySelector('input[name=sessionID]').value = 'some new value';
```

Comment: I think I see your point, but how is it possible to change sessionID then?

Comment: I mean why is it possible to change the sessionID and not its value?